# kendo editor: prevent keydown not working

Tags: kendo-ui, editor, onkeydown

I would like to prevent the pressing of ENTER if the kendo editor body has a certain height (to limit the max height of the editor field). But none of my tries worked.

```
<textarea data-role="editor"
          data-bind="events: { keydown: onEditorKeyDown }">
</textarea>

viewModel.onEditorKeyDown = function (e) {
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if (key == 13) {
                var editor = e.sender;
                var body = editor.body;
                var height = body.scrollHeight;
                if (height > 195) {
                    ?? //tried e.preventDefault(), return false etc.
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find two solutions. One is dirty hack and other doesn't match your requirements 100%. But both perform what is needed more or less.

New paragraph is added via embedded editor `insertParagraph` command which overrides default keydown logic. So the first solution is to temporary override this command using `keydown` and `keyup` events like this:

```
<textarea data-role="editor" 
    data-bind="events: { keydown: onEditorKeyDown, keyup: onEditorKeyUp }">
</textarea>
```

```js
// this should probably be moved to viewModel, it's here for demo puproses only
var savedCommand;
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    html: null,
    isVisible: true,
    onChange: function() {
        kendoConsole.log("event :: change (" + kendo.htmlEncode(this.get("html")) + ")");
    }
});

viewModel.onEditorKeyDown = function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (key == 13) {
            var editor = e.sender;
            var body = editor.body;
            var height = body.scrollHeight;
            if (height > 195) {
                savedCommand = editor.toolbar.tools.insertParagraph.command;
                editor.toolbar.tools.insertParagraph.command = function() {};
            }
        }
    };

viewModel.onEditorKeyUp = function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (key == 13) {
            if (savedCommand) {
                var editor = e.sender;
                editor.toolbar.tools.insertParagraph.command = savedCommand;
                savedCommand = undefined;
            }
        }
    };

kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
```

This works fine, but looks a bit ugly.

Other solution is to execute editor undo command if needed. It works too, but empty line always flickers for a moment:

```
<textarea data-role="editor"
    data-bind="events: { keyup: onEditorKeyUp }"></textarea>
```

```js
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    html: null,
    isVisible: true,
    onChange: function() {
        kendoConsole.log("event :: change (" + kendo.htmlEncode(this.get("html")) + ")");
    }
});

viewModel.onEditorKeyUp = function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (key == 13) {
            var editor = e.sender;
            var body = editor.body;
            while (body.scrollHeight > 195) {
                editor.exec('undo');
            }
        }
    };

kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
```

UPD: I've found event better solution. You can use `execute` event, see http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor#events-execute

Then check conditions and filter by command name to cancel insert of new paragraph:

```
execute: function(e) {
  alert(e.name);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hi, your first solution is absolutely fine for me! (The second approach somehow does not work as well.) You really earned the reputation!

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald I've found one more solution approach that seems more valid. Check update in the end of the answer. Unfortunately I don't have time to try it and make a complete example now.